# Bootstrap modal not showing on page reload with specific url parameters

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, url, parameters, ready

I am trying to automatically show a bootstrap modal which needs to open on page load. The first time the page is loaded it works. If the regular `<a>` element to open the modal is clicked, a small form is sent to the same page to pass some variables as `_GET` parameters. After that the bootstrap modal should open again but it does only when the url is edit.php? `cat=Producten&id=0&action=change` and not from edit.php?`cat=Afbeeldingen&id=0&action=change`. (both urls sent using the same form).

This is the modal html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editDialog" role="dialog"><!-- Edit dialog modal -->
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">         
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title"><?php echo $cat; ?></h4>
                </div><!-- /modal-header-->
                <form name="editForm" id="editForm" action="edit.php?cat=<?php echo $cat;?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">                                 

                            </div><!-- /col-sm-12 -->
                        </div><!-- /row -->
                    </div><!-- /modal-body -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" id="submit" value="Opslaan" style="display:none;"/><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
                    </div><!-- /modal-footer -->
                </form>
            </div><!-- /modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /modal -->
```

This is the small form that sends the parameters:

```
<form id="changeUrl" action="" method="get">
        <input type="hidden" id="send_cat" name="cat" value="<?php echo $_GET['cat'];?>"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="send_id" name="id"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="send_action" name="action"/>
    </form>
```

This is the jquery script:

```
<script>            
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var id;
            var action;

            $('.editToggle').click(function(){                  
                id = $(this).data('id');
                action = $(this).data('action');
                $('#send_id').val(id);
                $('#send_action').val(action);
                $('#changeUrl').submit();                   
            });

            $('#editDialog').modal('toggle');                                       
        });         
    </script>
```

To conclude, the last jQuery action is working when the url is edit.php? `cat=Producten&id=0&action=change` but not when the url is edit.php?`cat=Afbeeldingen&id=0&action=change`.

Comment: I see that you're using PHP. But why in the second URL are there `$` before variable names?

Comment: My bad, a typo. But in the code sends the Form with method=get so the page reloads and then there is an URL  & signs before the parameters. They are almost the same except for the ?cat parameter. However the jquery $('#editDialog').modal('toggle') fires only when the URL has only the ?cat parameter or when there is ?cat=Products&id=something&action=something. It does not fire if the URL is the same but with cat=Afbeeldingen.  With both variants some PHP is loaded,  whereby cat=Producten is taking somewhat longer to load.